# bash command fails when used with variables

Tags: linux, bash

I use a Linux (Ubuntu) bash.
When I ping an address dirrectly - all work fine.
But when I use it with a variable that gets it's value from calculation - it fails.

what am i doing wrong?

```bash
network=`ip r | grep default | awk '{print $3;}'`
echo $network   # prints: 10.0.0.138
ping $network   # prints: ping: 10.0.0.138: Name or service not known (ERROR???)
ping 10.0.0.138 # prints: PING 10.0.0.138 (10.0.0.138) 56(84) bytes of data. (OK)
```

Comment: Use `set -x` to find out what is stored in `$network`.

Comment: + set -x '10.0.0.138'

Comment: with quotes (???) - that's probably the problem

Comment: There's probably some sort of nonprinting character in `$network` causing trouble. Rather than `echo $network`, try `printf %s "$network" | xxd` and see what that shows.

Comment: 00000000: 1b5b 3335 6d31 302e 302e 302e 3133 38    .[35m10.0.0.138

Answer (score 2):

it's becaues the result is colored...
`ip`is aliased to `ip -c`

so - this had solved the issue:

```
 network=`/usr/bin/ip r | grep default | awk '{print $3;}'`
```

Answer (score -1):

That sequence should work OK at the command line (it'd be interesting to see a screenshot). However you can lose the grep and use a more rigorous awk script:

```
defaultgw=$(ip r | awk '{if ($1=="default") print $3}')
```

Then just send a single echo-request without any name resolution:

```
ping -n -c 1 $defaultgw
```

Comment: dudu@dudu-pc:~$ defaultgw=$(ip r | awk '{if ($1=="default") print $3}')
dudu@dudu-pc:~$ ping -n -c 1 $defaultgw
ping: 10.0.0.138: Name or service not known

Comment: it should, but it doesn't